# Looking for a way to display a div and hide other divs on link click

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page that contains a number of questions that have links with answers directly below each.  I want to hide all answers and display only the one for the question that was clicked.  I've seen code where all of the hidden divs are at the end.  How do I have them appear right after each link?  I'd like to use jQuery and/or CSS to do this.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I think it can help you.

```js
function faqClick(faqFocus) {
    var focused = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-wrap");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < focused.length; i++) {
        var under = focused[i];
        if (under.classList.contains('faq-wrap') && under!=faqFocus) {
            under.classList.remove('faq-wrap');
        }
    }
    if (faqFocus.classList.contains('faq-wrap')) {
        faqFocus.classList.remove('faq-wrap');
    }
    else {
        faqFocus.classList.add('faq-wrap');
    }
}
```

```css
.faq-content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 2.5;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: height .4s ease;
}
.faq-content div:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.faq-content div:last-child:first-letter {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.faq-content:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.faq-wrap {
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq-content" onclick="event.stopPropagation(); faqClick(this)">
    <div>Q. What is this?</div>
    <div>A. This is a sample text.</div>
</div>
<div class="faq-content" onclick="event.stopPropagation(); faqClick(this)">
    <div>Q. What is this?</div>
    <div>A. This is a sample text.</div>
</div>
<div class="faq-content" onclick="event.stopPropagation(); faqClick(this)">
    <div>Q. What is this?</div>
    <div>A. This is a sample text.</div>
</div>
<div class="faq-content" onclick="event.stopPropagation(); faqClick(this)">
    <div>Q. What is this?</div>
    <div>A. This is a sample text.</div>
</div>
<div class="faq-content" onclick="event.stopPropagation(); faqClick(this)">
    <div>Q. What is this?</div>
    <div>A. This is a sample text.</div>
</div>
<div class="faq-content" onclick="event.stopPropagation(); faqClick(this)">
    <div>Q. What is this?</div>
    <div>A. This is a sample text.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this code will be very helpful, though I don't need the horizontal lines between, but that is an easy change. Now, can I do this with SharePoint? I am doing this at work and they use SharePoint, but I haven't really used SharePoint in the past.